# Chrome PDF viewer snaps back to the same page

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, pdf-reader

When attempting to scroll down the PDF, chrome snaps back to the same page after reaching a certain point.
This only happens with one PDF, and this occurs only in chrome.

Below is a gif of it occurring

[Gif of error](https://gifs.com/gif/gLq6ZG)

EDIT:

Using bookmarks to navigate the PDF does not work either.